# Cmake with GLFW

Tags: cmake, clang, glfw

Cannot create proper CMakeLists.txt file - Cmake tells that

> CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "GLFW".
> CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: GLFW
> Generating done (0.0s)
> CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include/GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include "include/GLFW/glfw3native.h"

int main()
{
return 0;
}
~
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15...3.25)

project(MyProject
  VERSION
    1.0
  DESCRIPTION
    "Very nice project"
  LANGUAGES
    CXX
)

add_library(GLFW
include/GLFW/glfw3.h
include/GLFW/glfw3native.h
lib/libglfw3.a
)

add_executable(myexample letter.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myexample PRIVATE GLFW)
```

tree looks like:

```
a1312@MacBook-Air-1312 source % tree
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── GLFW
│       ├── glfw3.h
│       └── glfw3native.h
├── letter
├── letter.cpp
├── letters.cpp
└── lib
    ├── libglfw.3.dylib
    └── libglfw3.a

4 directories, 8 files
```

What am I doing wrong?

Already tried steps from glfw-site, but it not helped

Comment: It seems that you want to link with the already existed `.a` library file. Specifying that library file in `add_library` call is wrong. You may want to create IMPORTED library and specify that file in its IMPORTED_LOCATION property, like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550334/3440745) to the duplicate question.